# Relative path for a included file - ASP/HTML

Tags: asp-classic, include, relative-path, include-path, document-root

Sorry if this question is answered somewhere else but I tried searching several pages and was unsuccessful.

So i have an include file (sidebar) which i am using in all pages.

```
Default.asp
Products.asp
Salary/Survey.asp
inc/sidebar.asp (this is the included file)
```

now inside `sidebar.asp` I have a link for `Salary/Survey.asp`

from all other pages at root level, i can simply use `href='Salary/Survey.asp'` and will work fine. but when I am on page `Survey.asp` , writing `href='Salary/Survey.asp'` will become actually `Salary/Salary/Survey.asp`. I understand it has to be `../Salary/Survey.asp` to be used properly but it will then not work for root level pages.

I can not use `root relative` which is `/Default.asp` and `/Salary/Survey.asp` as I am working for someone else' project and i dont know his directory structure and thus i only have option to `document relative` path.

Hope this is clear to understand and someone helps me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this problem the following way...

1. Each of our asp pages included a special file that **Dims** and sets **golbal variables**. We called ours **Info.asp**
2. Inside **Info.asp** we defined a variable called **strRelativePath**
   Dim **strRelativePath**
   **strRelativePath** = ""
3. Every asp page set the relative path according to it relative position:

for example:

- Root pages - strRelativePath = ""
- One level deep pages - strRelativePath = "../"
- Two levels deep pages - strRelativePath = "../../"

Then it was a matter of prefacing all the links requiring a relative path with <%=**strRelativePath**%>

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to get write this after the that - Salary/Survey.asp
You can get the virtual path to the file from one of several server variables - try either:

Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
```

Either server variable will give you the virtual path including any sub-directories and the file name - given your example, you'll get `/virtual_directory/subdirectory/file.asp`. If you just want the virtual directory, you'll need to strip off everything after the second forward slash using whatever method you prefer for plucking a directory out of a path, such as:

```
s = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
i = InStr(2, s, "/")
If i > 0 Then
    s = Left(s, i - 1)
End If
or:

s = "/" & Split(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), "/")(1)
```

Comment: thank you all for the answers. I liked Jatin's method however I eneded up using Cape Cod Gunny's answer as I also had similar thought in my mind. Thanks again for all help.

Answer (score 0):

basically, if your sidebar can be included from programs in different folders, the only 'easy' way is to use absolute paths like you mentioned.

You say can't use it, so I would think of different ways...

- virtual folders: In IIS you could set a virtual folder in salary folder for 'salary' and point it to the site's root.
- OS links (similar to above, but at the OS level)
- use mappath. You could check mappath to see the actual folder you're in, and use the correct include (with/without /salary) though I'm thinking this might give you an error, not sure.